# Windows Form won't pass a variable to another?

Tags: vb.net

my problem is that is have 4 forms, 3 of these forms allow me to pass variables between them.. however one form the Booking form won't allow me to pass the txtTotal variable to the Confirmation Form.

All the other forms all me to do this, im not doing anything different i can see... im thinking that perhaps another part of the form is prohibiting me from passing that txtTotal to the Confirmatin form.

The following is for the Confirmation form, it should display the txtTotal in lblprice from the Booking form but shows nothing

```
Public Class Confirmation

    Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        Dim FrmPayment As New Payment
        FrmPayment.Show()

        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnHome_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHome.Click
        Dim FrmSelection As New Selection
        FrmSelection.Show()

        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblshow.Click, lbltime.Click, lbldate.Click, lblcust.Click, lblprice.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Confirmation_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'lblprice displays nothing and the rest of the labels display the correct values
        lblprice.Text = Booking.txtTotal.Text

        lblshow.Text = Selection.cboShowSelect.Text
        lbldate.Text = Selection.cboDateSelect.Text
        lbltime.Text = Selection.cboTimeSelect.Text

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is all the code in the Booking form if it helps

```
Public Class Booking

    Private Sub Booking_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'labels 1,4,6 display information from the comboboxes on the Selection Form
        Label1.Text = Selection.cboShowSelect.Text
        Label4.Text = Selection.cboDateSelect.Text
        Label6.Text = Selection.cboTimeSelect.Text


        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 4
            cboAdult.Items.Add(i)
            cboChild.Items.Add(i)
            cboSenior.Items.Add(i)
            cboStudent.Items.Add(i)
        Next i

    End Sub





    Public Sub ComboBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboAdult.SelectedIndexChanged, cboChild.SelectedIndexChanged, cboSenior.SelectedIndexChanged, cboStudent.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Assigned an evet handler to all of the comboboxes then calculates the price and puts in total box

        Dim Totalcombo1, Totalcombo2, Totalcombo3, Totalcombo4, Price As Decimal

        Dim valuecombo1 = (cboAdult.SelectedIndex + 1)  'finds position of option selected & adds one to get number of tickets
        Dim valuecombo2 = (cboChild.SelectedIndex + 1)
        Dim valuecombo3 = (cboSenior.SelectedIndex + 1)
        Dim valuecombo4 = (cboStudent.SelectedIndex + 1)


        'if the submit button is selected without there being a value selected from any combobox then error should appear, saying at least 1 ticket should be purchased.
        If (cboChild.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
            Totalcombo2 = 0
        Else
            Price = 6.5
            Totalcombo2 = valuecombo2 * Price
        End If

        'determines the ticketprice of combobox 1


        If (cboAdult.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
            Totalcombo1 = 0
        Else
            Price = 9
            Totalcombo1 = valuecombo1 * Price
        End If
        'determines the ticketprice of combobox 2


        If (cboSenior.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
            Totalcombo3 = 0
        Else
            Price = 6.5
            Totalcombo3 = valuecombo3 * Price
        End If
        'determines the ticketprice of combobox 3


        If (cboStudent.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
            Totalcombo4 = 0
        Else
            Price = 6.5
            Totalcombo4 = valuecombo4 * Price
        End If
        'determines the ticketprice of combobox 4


        If (cboAdult.SelectedIndex = -1 And cboChild.SelectedIndex = -1 And cboSenior.SelectedIndex = -1 And cboStudent.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please make at least one ticket selection before continuing. ")
        End If





        txtTotal.Text = Totalcombo1 + Totalcombo2 + Totalcombo3 + Totalcombo4
        'adds the totals of the ticketprices and then inserts into the Total label


    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboChild.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnBack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        Dim FrmSelection As New Selection
        FrmSelection.Show()

        Me.Hide()
    End Sub



    Sub Form_OpenBooking(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If (cboChild.SelectedIndex >= 0 And (cboSenior.SelectedIndex = -1 And cboAdult.SelectedIndex = -1)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("A child must be accompanied by at least one adult", "Invalid Selection")

        ElseIf (txtTotal.Text > 0) Then         'if the total label is greater than zero then this means at least one ticket selection has been made

            Dim Form3 As New Payment     ' if above is true open Booking Form
            Form3.Show()

            Me.Hide()
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub Resetbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        cboAdult.SelectedIndex = -1

        cboChild.SelectedIndex = -1

        cboSenior.SelectedIndex = -1

        cboStudent.SelectedIndex = -1

        txtTotal.Text = 0
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the visibility of your txtTotal Control is it Private or Public

Comment: Your Class Name is Booking what is the name of the Form when you create it? Judging by your code that is creating your payment form,  is it frmBooking ?

Comment: Would be better to check has the `ComboBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged` been fired. You can assign a value into txtTotal in `Booking_Load` and see whether you can get it.

Comment: @Nick That is one of the reasons I suggested that he set a breakpoint, anything past this point is pure conjecture without seeing his entire app.

Comment: Yes @MarkHall, it is good to set a breakpoint to check the flow step-by-step.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Public frm as new frmBooking
frm.txtTotal.Text=
```

It should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the actual instance of the Form that you created, not the Class name. You should also make sure that you turn on [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

Try `frmBooking.txtTotal.Text` instead of `Booking.txtTotal.Text`

Comment: put a breakpoint on `lblprice.Text = frmBooking.txtTotal.Text` and Step through your code to see what is going on. Also is this VB.net or Vb6